# Show the problem of flat base change is local on the source and target

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, flatness

[image: Exercise]

(The picture is from Exercise 5.1.16 in QingLiu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curve) All the proofs I saw on any reference usually start with "the problem is local on $T$ and on $S$ so we may suppose $S$ and $T$ are affine". I used to accept it handwavely but when I want to write a rigourous proof on my own I can't make it rigourous.

Assume we have proved the theorem for the case $T$ and $S$ are affine, can anyone provide a rigorous proof for this theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it. It involves a lot of checkings of commutativity.
We are going to need the following 2 claims as basic tools for commutativity.
[image]

(The counter didn't start with 1 because I just copied the picture from my notes) They can be proved using the push-forward-pull-back adjointness.

We first reduce to the case $T$ is affine via the following claim:
[image]
[image]

Then we reduce to the case $S$ is affine.
[image]

[image]

---

At the demand of the comment by @BernyPiffaro, I add the following proof about the case $S$ and $T$ are affine.

Assume now $S$ and $T$ are affine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: At the very beginning of the proof of claim 4 you realize the restriction to the open $U$ by the pullback, but shouldn't you use the inverse image sheaf instead?

Comment: @BernyPiffaro In the case of open immersions, they agree, i.e. $i^*\mathcal{F}=i^{-1}\mathcal{F}$. In the context of sheaf of modules over a space, we use pullbacks because the inverse image operator doesn't gurantee the result is a sheaf of modules.

Comment: You are right (I'will delete my answer). I read again your proof and I agree, but it isn't complete, is it? If I got it we still have to prove the theorem for $T$ and $S$ affine. Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: @BernyPiffaro Yes I didn't prove it for $T$ and $S$ affine becuase the (my) question assumed that is solved. Now I have added the proof for this case in my answer.